# Change data types using a list of data type names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

What is an elegant way to change the data types of data frames columns from a list of data type names?

Here's an example (change_to_data_types function is what I'm looking for):

```
my_df <- iris
my_types <- c("factor", "character", "double", "logical", "character")
my_df <- my_df %>% change_to_data_types(my_types)
```

`my_types` has the same number of elements as the number of columns in `my_df` and the conversion is done in the same order.

This is an example of an 'inelegant' way

```
my_df$Sepal.Length <- my_df$Sepal.Length %>% as.factor()
my_df$Sepal.Width <- my_df$Sepal.Width %>% as.character()
#etc...
```

Comment: Just a doubt, wouldn't this better to do while reading the data itself i.e. there are easier option in `colClasses` while reading

Comment: Maybe define colClasses  when reading in the data? Something like: `mydf <- read.table(..., colClasses = c("factor", "character", "double", "logical", "character")`

Comment: The dataframes are in a list after splitting a larger table that comes with mixed datatypes.

Comment: That might turn into "XY Problem", why not then ensure the list is created by the same dataframe structures?

Comment: The split is done by a single column in the original dataframe, and that column is the only column common to all the dataframes.  I don't control the original dataframe or the structures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An option would be

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df[] <- map2(my_df, str_c("as.", my_types), ~ get(.y)(.x))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
my_df[] <- Map(function(x, y) get(y)(x), my_df, paste0("as.", my_types))
```

-checking the class again

```
sapply(my_df, class)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#    "factor"  "character"    "numeric"    "logical"  "character"
```

Comment: wow, what's goingon with `get()`? It gets the function from the string and takes the object within the second parantheses as input for said function? Haven't seen that before.

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen  It returns the function value and the `()` is the input for that function.  here, it is `as.factor(column)`

Answer (score 5):

Having fun with *match.fun*:

```
my_df[] <- lapply(seq_along(names(my_df)),
                  function(i) match.fun(paste0("as.", my_types[ i ]))(my_df[[ i ]]))


sapply(my_df, class)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#     "factor"  "character"    "numeric"    "logical"  "character"
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**:
To avoid having malformed factors due to the direct conversion of numerics to factors, we can do:

```
lapply(seq_along(names(my_df)),
                 function(x){
                   if(is.numeric(my_df[,x]) &
                      my_types[x] =="factor"){
                    as.factor(as.character(my_df[,x]))
                   } 
                   else{
                     as(my_df[,x],my_types[x])
                   }
                 }
                   )
```

**ORIGINAL**:

We can do:

```
sapply(seq_along(names(my_df)),
       function(x)  as(my_df[,x],my_types[x]))
```

Comment: I found it hard to use with `map2`, formed malformed factors.

Comment: This returns a matrix, which means all columns are of the same class.

Comment: I think you need to change from `sapply` to `lapply` and assign back the output

Comment: should be smth like `my_df[] <- lapply(seq_along(my_df), function(x) as(my_df[[x]], my_types[x]))`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Edited, your opinion on the edit will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mapply` to feed `utils::as` pairs of columns and types. This won't work for the factor columns, so those are handled separately.

```
fcols <- my_types == "factor"
my_df[!fcols] <- mapply(as, my_df[!fcols], my_types[!fcols], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
my_df[fcols] <- lapply(my_df[fcols], factor)
```

Comment: why not do it just in one lapply() call?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Personal taste, really.  I find this easier to read than creating a function with `if`/`else` logic for a single `mapply`.  Your mileage may vary.