# Writing a custom function to convert class of variables in a dataframe based on another table

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function that could take in:

- data frame (`df_1`) whose columns' classes need to be converted
- another data frame (`df_2`) that has a *row* for each variable of `df_1`
- a column in `df_2` that specifies the class each variable in `df_1` should be converted to

### Example

### 1 -- Data frame (`df_1`) with my data (and variables' classes to convert)

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2021)

df_1 <-
  tibble(name = c("john", "jack", "mary", "matt", "elizabeth", "richard", "carlos", "george", "ferdinand", "william"), 
       height = sample(155:200, size = 10),
       weight = sample(50:100, size = 10),
       age = sample(20:100, size = 10),
       gender = sample(c("male", "female"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
       preferred_pet = sample(c("dog", "cat", "frog", "rabbit"), size= 10, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))

## # A tibble: 10 x 6
##    name      height weight age   gender preferred_pet
##    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>        
##  1 john      161    100    38    female frog         
##  2 jack      192    67     87    female dog          
##  3 mary      193    52     24    male   rabbit       
##  4 matt      166    95     92    male   dog          
##  5 elizabeth 160    89     82    female cat          
##  6 richard   199    75     57    male   dog          
##  7 carlos    195    85     37    female rabbit       
##  8 george    159    86     62    male   rabbit       
##  9 ferdinand 177    71     78    female cat          
## 10 william   197    80     89    female rabbit
```

### 2 -- Data frame (`df_2`) with classes to convert `df_1` columns to

```r
set.seed(2021)

df_2 <-
  tibble(var_name =  c("name", "height", "weight", "gender", "preferred_pet", "record_creation"),
         var_class = c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "factor", "factor", "datetime")) %>%
  slice(sample(1:n()))

## # A tibble: 6 x 2
##   var_name        var_class
##   <chr>           <chr>    
## 1 weight          numeric  
## 2 record_creation datetime 
## 3 height          numeric  
## 4 name            character
## 5 gender          factor   
## 6 preferred_pet   factor
```

### 3 -- Building a function for class conversion

I've seen @akrun's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773548/6105259), which seems pretty close to what I'm trying to achieve.

```r
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

my_df <- iris
my_types <- c("factor", "character", "double", "logical", "character")
my_df[] <- map2(my_df, str_c("as.", my_types), ~ get(.y)(.x))
```

However, this solution doesn't address situations like mine, where variable names of `df_1` don't necessarily appear in `df_2`, and similarly, `df_2$var_name` includes variables that don't necessarily appear in `df_1`.

I'll be glad for any idea for constructing a function for converting `df_1`'s vars classes according to info found in `df_2`. Finding a solution using `tidyverse` functions would be ideal.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach leveraging `across` and `cur_column`:

```
library(dplyr) #version >= 1.0.0
df_1 %>% 
  mutate(across(any_of(df_2$var_name), 
                ~get(paste0("as.",df_2[df_2$var_name == cur_column(),"var_class"]))(.x)))
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   name      height weight age   gender preferred_pet
   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <fct>  <fct>        
 1 john         161    100 38    female frog         
 2 jack         192     67 87    female dog          
 3 mary         193     52 24    male   rabbit       
 4 matt         166     95 92    male   dog          
 5 elizabeth    160     89 82    female cat          
 6 richard      199     75 57    male   dog          
 7 carlos       195     85 37    female rabbit       
 8 george       159     86 62    male   rabbit       
 9 ferdinand    177     71 78    female cat          
10 william      197     80 89    female rabbit
```

The `any_of` selection helper insures that you only try to mutate columns that are present in `df_2`.

The second argument is the function that is applied to the columns that are present. You can use `cur_column()` to have access to the name of the column that is being mutated. From there, we just look up that column name in `df_2` and return the `var_class` you want. Then use `get()` from base R to return the appropriate function and apply that to the column with `(.x)`.

If you wanted to define a function, and pass the column names unquoted as you would with other tidyverse functions, you could use `rlang::enquo`:

```
library(rlang)
change_class_by_table <- function(data,data_ref,column_name,column_class){
data %>% 
  mutate(across(any_of(pull(data_ref,!!enquo(column_name))), 
                ~get(paste0("as.",filter(data_ref, !!enquo(column_name) == cur_column()) %>%
                                    pull(!!enquo(column_class))))(.x)))
}
change_class_by_table(df_1,df_2,var_name,var_class)
## A tibble: 10 x 6
#   name      height weight age   gender preferred_pet
#   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <fct>  <fct>        
# 1 john         161    100 38    female frog         
# 2 jack         192     67 87    female dog          
# 3 mary         193     52 24    male   rabbit  
# ...
```

Comment: See the edit for how to do it with unquoted column names