# Can dplyr add the values from merged columns together?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one dataframe with staff (in ~8 different positions) assigned at many (~70+) different locations, e.g.

| Location | Job1 | Job2 | Job3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| B | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

I have another dataframe with openings (unstaffed positions), but the columns are not in the same order. e.g.

| Location | Job2 | Job1 | Job3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 4 | 1 | 6 |

I'm ultimately looking for a summary table that shows the staffing rate by location/position, e.g.

| Location | Job1 | Job2 | Job3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.50 | 1.00 | 0.75 | 0.75 |
| B | 0.50 | 0.83 | 0.86 | 0.54 |

So far, I have successfully merged the first two tables together (using `left_join` because there are some locations with no unfilled jobs that are simply not present in the shortages table) with `by = location, suffix = c(".f", ".uf")` for filled and unfilled, leading to a table that looks like:

| Location | Job1.f | Job2.f | Job3.f | Total.f | Job2.uf | Job1.uf | Job3.uf | Total.uf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 6 |

Question: Is there any way (other than looping over job types, using `dplyr` if possible) to mutate the columns based on matching names, for example `data %>% mutate(fill_rate1 = Job1.f / (Job1.f + Job1.uf))` without manually typing a separate line for each job type? My inclination says there should be some "wildcard"/regex matching techniques, but so far I haven't had any luck.

EDIT: Reproducible code below

```r
library(tidyverse)

locations <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
job1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
job2 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
job3 <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
total <- c(18, 21, 24, 27, 30)

loc_uf <- c("A","B","E")
uf1 <- c(0,2,4)
uf2 <- c(3,6,9)
uf3 <- c(7,3,0)
uftotal <- c(10, 11, 13)

filled <- data_frame(locations = locations, Job1 = job1, Job2 = job2, Job3 = job3,
                     total = total)

unfilled <- data_frame(locations = loc_uf, Job2 = uf2, Job1 = uf1, Job3 = uf3,
                       total = uftotal)

merged <- left_join(filled, unfilled, by = "locations", suffix = c(".f", ".uf")) %>%
          replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible piece of your data so that others can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be easier if you use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to reshape the data to long format, so as jobs are in one column and values in another.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Location) %>% 
  left_join(pivot_longer(df2, cols = -Location), by = c("Location", "name")) %>%
  mutate(rate = value.x / (value.x + value.y))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  Location name  value.x value.y  rate
  <chr>    <chr>   <int>   <int> <dbl>
1 A        Job1        1       1 0.5  
2 A        Job2        2       0 1    
3 A        Job3        3       1 0.75 
4 A        Total       6       2 0.75 
5 B        Job1        4       4 0.5  
6 B        Job2        5       1 0.833
7 B        Job3        6       1 0.857
8 B        Total       7       6 0.538
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location = c("A", "B"), 
                      Job1 = c(1L, 4L), 
                      Job2 = c(2L, 5L), 
                      Job3 = c(3L, 6L), 
                      Total = 6:7), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(Location = c("A", "B"), 
                      Job2 = 0:1, 
                      Job1 = c(1L, 4L), 
                      Job3 = c(1L, 1L), 
                      Total = c(2L, 6L)), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is with `across`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
  mutate(across(contains(".f"),
                ~ ./(. + get(str_replace(cur_column(),".f",".uf"))),
                .names = "fillrate_{.col}"))
#  Location Job1.f Job2.f Job3.f Total.f Job2.uf Job1.uf Job3.uf Total.uf fillrate_Job1.f fillrate_Job2.f fillrate_Job3.f fillrate_Total.f
#1        A      1      2      3       6       0       1       1        2             0.5       1.0000000       0.7500000        0.7500000
#2        B      4      5      6       7       1       4       1        6             0.5       0.8333333       0.8571429        0.5384615
```

Comment: I guess I used this `get` based approach some time back for a solution (not sure if somebody else done that before).  In the current version it works, but it may require some changes as I find many questions asking similar things.  It would be also good to know the efficiency of this approach with the pivot_longer approach

Comment: @akrun I agree it would be helpful to have a robust Q & A that compares the efficiency, particularly since this problem pops up [not infrequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541605/writing-a-custom-function-to-convert-class-of-variables-in-a-dataframe-based-on/65542012#65542012).