# R Convert datatype of a list of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773354/change-data-types-using-a-list-of-data-type-names), I would like to do the same but to a list of `tibbles`.

How can I do this?

Sample Data & code:

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl1 = tibble(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = 1:3)
tbl2 = tibble(x = c('11', '12', '13'), y = 1:3)

tbl = list(tbl1, tbl2)

data_types = rep(c("character"),times = 3)

tbl[] = map2(tbl, str_c("as.", data_types), ~ get(.y)(.x))
```

Error:

```
Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 2
* `.y` has length 3
```

Comment: Why is your lenght of `data_types 3 when the columns are of length 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked post, it is having different column types, so we created a vector of types with length equal to the number of columns in the data.  Here, the number of columns in each of the datasets in the `list` is 2.  Thus, the `rep` with `times` should be `2`

```
data_types <- rep(c("character"),times = 2)
```

Also, as we have to loop over the list, do a nested `map/map2`

```
library(purrr)
map(tbl, ~ map2_dfr(.x, str_c("as.", data_types), ~ get(.y)(.x)))
```

Or as there is a single type, we can also do

```
map(tbl,  ~map_dfr(.x, as.character))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     1    
2 b     2    
3 c     3    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 11    1    
2 12    2    
3 13    3
```